How to include an xml in the classified Uber jar and exclude that xml in normal jar in mvn clean package command
In a maven project, maven-jar-plugin and maven-shade-plugin with classifier are configured in pom.xml:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/persistence.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>uber</shadedClassifierName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>io.github.rxue.dictionary.jpa.Main</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

Problem
uber-JAR is generated by maven-shade-plugin on base of the jar generated by maven-jar-plugin. So as long as META-INF/persistence.xml is excluded by maven-jar-plugin, META-INF/persistence.xml is excluded in the generated uber-JAR as well
Question
How to exclude META-INF/persistence.xml in the normal jar but include META-INF/persistence.xml in the uber-JAR with man clean package command in one go?
The purpose of generating jars in one goal is so that mvn deploy can deploy all the jars into the Maven Central Repository

Try using Maven Build Profiles

@seenukarthi I actually tried Maven build profiles in the first place already, and that did not achieve the goal of generating all jars including uber-JAR in one go. But if you could give a complete answer, please put the answer there, thanks in advance
